# How to embed Skype in my App

Tags: android

Zoopla have embedded Google Maps into their app (see the screen shot)

Is this something you can do generally, i.e. embed any app in your own, or is it specific just to Google Maps?

I want to do the same with Skype, is that possible?

Edit: I know how to launch Skype as a separate app using URI's, using ..

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", "skype:some_skype_id");
startActivity(intent);
```

... but I want Skype to appear as running within my app, in particular to keep my action bar visible at the top.

Thanks

Damian.

[image: Google Maps embedded in Zoopla]

Comment: maybe via url-schemes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I guess the summary is that it can't be done for Skype; Zoopla have achieved it in this case because Google Maps publish a specific API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zoopla is using the API provided for Maps, namely [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

Skype does not provide such tools, but they do have an [API for developers](https://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/reference) you may want to look into.

Answer (score 1):

Skype does have a Public API http://developer.skype.com/ that works via URI-Schemes

This page has a wealth of information on how to use the API and the various commands. There is no public framework which abstracts it any further so you'll need to investigate how to make the actual commands by deconstructing the various wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

SkypeKit (software+API) allows devices or applications connected to the internet to offer Skype voice and video calls... Look here https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12322/what-is-skypekit.
Skype URIs enable developers to create mobile, web, and desktop apps that initiate Skype calls and chats.
http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris