# How to embed Hangout chat in my Android App

Tags: android, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

my question is similar to the below one...
[How to embed Skype in my App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076851/how-to-embed-skype-in-my-app)

I have an android application. There we have a option to chat with our google contact user. So, We planned to use the hangout chat to achieve. Now, I just want to use the hangout chat in my android application. I should able to chat with the my google contact users from my own UI using hangout.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do without API. and API for that doesn't exist. I you want to create chat application you can use GCM.

You can write extentions for hangouts : [Hangouts API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/). 
But android application integration is not possible at this moment. (And i think it never will be, because they have their protocol)

You have only one way to do this. Download `whireshark` or `fidler` and see what `http` requests are sent/received during the chat on your android or web hangouts chat. :)

But still i think they have some authentication and hashing that will make this impossible.

Comment: @loane: thanks for reply... ok... Is it possible with any of these Skype, Facebook, Whatsapp?

Comment: I remembered that hangouts use GCM, so no it's not possible to make hangouts in your application because you need private keys. 

Also you can't make Whatsapp for the same reason. 

You can make facebook application because I know some facebook client chats. :) 

Skype has some NAT traversal algorithms and `supernode` users, so it'll be hard to make you client unless they provide API. 

Note that they might change API's time to time, so you'll need to update your application even if you write...

Comment: @loane: Thx a lot... Is it possible integrate any other chat application? Like third party or paid app anything. I just want to integrate live chat into my application. Don't want to create own chat application. Please guide me on this.

Comment: Yes, I said that only way is to look at live chat using `whireshark` , you will see what requests are transferred during the live chat. I don't know if this will be possible, maybe they use private key for authentication that only company's genuine application is possible to send request on server.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Video is one possible solution.

The Android QuickStart includes a complete Android Studio App you can download and try.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/quickstart-android

There are 4 key components to working with the API:

- User Identity and Access Tokens
- Conversations
- Video and Audio Tracks
- Event Webhooks

[Getting started with the Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/identity#client-initialization) looks like this:

```
// Create an AccessManager to manage our Access Token
AccessManager accessManager = new AccessManager(ConversationActivity.this,
                                ACCESS_TOKEN,
                                accessManagerListener());

// Create a Conversations Client and connect to Twilio's backend.
TwilioConversationsClient conversationsClient =
  TwilioConversationsClient.create(accessManager, conversationsClientListener());
conversationsClient.listen();

/* See the "Working with Conversations" guide for instructions on constructing a
ConversationsClientListener */
private TwilioConversationsClient.Listener conversationsClientListener() {
  return new TwilioConversationsClient.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onStartListeningForInvites(TwilioConversationsClient conversationsClient) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Connected to Twilio!");
    }

    ...

  };
}
```

*Please Note: I work for Twilio*