# Is it possible to intergrate Google Hangouts natively into an Android App?

Tags: android, webrtc, google-hangouts

I'm currently building an online tutoring app to help solve my country's crisis in education.

To do this, I need to integrate a video calling service. I'd prefer to use Hangouts over other services since it is based on webRTC and its free. However after much searching, I haven't found anything that explicitly states whether or not its possible to integrate it natively or through a webview. Do you have any ideas on how to go about doing this or if its even possible?

Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to integrate this functionality yet, the hangout API is web based and since hangout requires the camera there is no way to enable this from a webview.

See these answers:
[start google hangouts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127051/start-google-hangouts-in-android)

[Google hangout API for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227423/google-hangout-api-for-android)

[How to embed Hangout chat in my Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863348/how-to-embed-hangout-chat-in-my-android-app?rq=1)